# Link open new page with pre selected option (Dropdown)

Tags: jquery, select, hyperlink

I have a simple question that google cant answer me. Maybe i didnt find the right keywords for google.

I am on a "index.html" and there is a simple link like "Here". A click on this link brings me to e.g "contact.html". Is it possible that the link also preselect an certain option from a select dropdown?

For exmaple: I click on the link, this link brings me to contact.html and preselect the option "feedback".

```
<select name="subject">
<option value="question">Question</option>
<option value="feedback">Feedback</option>
<option value="product">Product</option>
</select>
```

Greetings from poland and sorry for my english ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
<select name="subject">
<option value="question">Question</option>
<option value="feedback" selected="selected">Feedback</option>
<option value="product">Product</option>
</select>
```

make link like this:

```
<a href="contact.html?pre=1">here</a>
```

Use this function on contact.html page

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

and use like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var preSelected = getParameterByName("pre");

if(preSelected == "1")
{

$('select[name="Subject"]').val("feedback");

}
});
```

Comment: of course i can do that, BUT the preselection depends on the link i click on ;) Link a preselect quetsion and Link b preselect feedback.

Comment: then you need to add some server side code in it, you are wokring in which language on this?

Comment: just html, css and a little bit jquery

Comment: so something like this on here anchor tag pass url like this: contact.html?pre=1 and with jqeury read url on feedback page and check if pre is 1 preselect feedback with jquery

Comment: see uodated answer, you will get your answer